# Select a column starting with '@' in databricks sql

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, hiveql, databricks

I'm getting to my through logstash into elasticsearch.
I import the data in databricks, first through a python scan and then transforming the data into a dataframe
The dataframe is then converted into temporary view within databricks. This view can then be used in sql modeling. This process can't be altered

When I query: `Select * from tempview` then I get all columns :)

[image]

Now the challenge: One of my field names is called *@timestamp* and I can see the databricks display that the column is there, but I can not select the column itself. In T-SQL I would have been able to use squarebrackets [@timestamp] and move on, but it does not work in hivesql.

I know that the @name syntax is reserved for sql variables, but is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backticks `

```
select `@timestamp`, `@version` from t
```

Spark shell example:

```
Seq((1, "a", "10")).toDF("id", "@version", "@timestamp").registerTempTable("t")
sql ("select `@timestamp`, `@version` from t").show

+----------+--------+
|@timestamp|@version|
+----------+--------+
|        10|       a|
+----------+--------+
```